# Removing Messenger Chatbot Default Quick Responses

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a functioning chatbot that I've developed. Only on facebook website (i.e. not on messenger site or app), when I click on the bot to begin a conversation for the first time, I get these default options, as show in the image.

[image]

I was wondering if there's some way to remove these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

Your Page->Settings->Messaging-> Turn off 'Help people start a conversation with your Page'

Comment: It's weird. I think it only showed me the above image while my app was under review. Now that the app is no longer in review, changing the "Prompt visitors to send messages" (which is what I assume you were referring to because "Help people start a conversation with your page" wasn't available), doesn't really change anything. The prompts are all gone regardless. However I still think that's the correct answer. Thanks!