# How to remove the default quick reply buttons

Tags: chatbot, messenger

I have developed a messenger chatbot that lets users inquire for their bills in our company. However, I noticed that there seems to be default buttons which I don't remember setting.
These buttons are unrelated to the functionality of the chatbot.

This issue is similar to this [S.O Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224651/removing-messenger-chatbot-default-quick-responses) where buttons show if the app is still not reviewed or such. I want to verify if this is really how it is and these [default] buttons will disappear after the app is approved.

**NOTE:**
These buttons seem to be showing only after a 24-hour period has passed, when I open the chat again the next day.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click a Page to go to it. In the left menu below Meta Business Suite, click Inbox. At the top, click Automations. Scroll down to Your automations, then click next to an automated message to turn it on or off.

Comment: Works perfect! There was indeed a default ```Frequently Asked Questions``` automation that was turned on. Turning it off solved it! Thank you!